# Use of pdb file in release build executables

Tags: c++, builds

This question is appropriate only for programs created on the windows platform.

If I build a release of my program with the /Zi option (create pdb file and store path to file in exe) then I don’t have to ship pdb file with release but we could retain for internal use.  The pdb file would be retained for our internal Quality Assurance use.  Then if a crash occurred, we have a system of printing the stack trace at the point of crash and this 'system' would have access to the exe symbols and we would get a nicely populated stack track in this file.

But there is a slight complication in that the final executable is created by a separate build dept in our company.  We developers can of course create a release build.

My query is that one of my colleagues is saying that the exe built by build team would be different from a release build created by us in development.  But I don’t understand why?  Is my colleague correct?  If so why?  And if so does this mean my plan for using pdb files with release builds is not possible?

Comment: Your real question seems to be, "Will compiling with the /Zi option change the outputted executable?", which I don't think is on topic for this site.

Comment: Why not have this release department build and give you PDBs?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to use the *exact* PDB file with the *exact* EXE file created together in the build. I don't have the details ready, but there are timestamps (and checksums?) in these files that will differ and prevent the whole thing from working *properly*.